# Convert recursive formula w exponent to explicit

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms, characteristic-polynomial

I have two recursive formulas that I don’t know how to convert to explicit form.

$$
x_1 = 3
$$
$$
x_n = x_{n-1} + 6*4^{n-2}
$$
$$
y_1 = 6
$$
$$
y_n = y_{n-1} + 15*4^{n-2}
$$

Since they follow the same format, instruction for converting either one should be enough enough for me to figure out the other. How do I convert?

Any method that finds a valid solution is appreciated, regardless of approach.

Comment: Hint: let $x_n = 4^{n-1} z_n$ then the first recurrence becomes $4 z_n = z_{n-1}+3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x_{1}=3, x_{2}=9$. Then, using the recursive definition, we have:
$$x_{n} = x_{n-1} + 6\cdot 4^{n-2}$$
$$x_{n+1} = x_{n}+6\cdot 4^{n-1}$$
Multiplying both sides of the first equation by $4$, and then subtracting it from the second equation:
$$x_{n+1}-4x_{n}=(x_{n}+6\cdot 4^{n-1})-4(x_{n-1}+6\cdot 4^{n-2})$$
$$x_{n+1}-5x_{n}+4x_{n-1}=0$$
Now, note that the characteristic polynomial for this recurrence is $r^{2}-5r+4$, with roots $r=1$ and $r=4$. Thus, we must have, for some constants $a$ and $b$:
$$x_{n}=a\cdot 4^{n}+b\cdot 1^{n}$$
Using the initial conditions:
$$x_{1}=3\Rightarrow 4a + b = 3$$
$$x_{2}=9\Rightarrow 16a + b = 9$$
Solving the system of equations, we find $\displaystyle(a,b) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2}, 1\bigg)$. Thus, $\displaystyle\boxed{x_{n}=\frac{4^{n}}{2}+1.}$

You can solve the second recurrence similarly.

Comment: Thank you! I confirmed this is correct and followed the same procedure for the second formula. I hadn’t learned about characteristic polynomials for a recurrence before, so that was key